# Why Does OpenGL Correctly Display Images with P3 Color Profile Without Special Configuration?

Tags: android, opengl-es, color-space, color-profile

I'm working on an OpenGL project in Android where I display images with a P3 color profile. Surprisingly, even without any special setup in my OpenGL surface, the images appear correctly on the screen. For example, I can see the logo in this P3 image clearly: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LqRniYeVeEk/XOLYEiOcKCI/AAAAAAAAJXI/IAn0yO21XYkwnkUnDlHtdPGI6VyMDEoeACLcBGAs/s1600/android_p3.png.

In my Android app, I decode all bitmaps with the `inPreferredColorSpace` set to `Display.getPreferredWideGamutColorSpace`. Therefore, the decoded bitmap could be in any color space (Display P3, sRGB, etc.) depending on the result of `inPreferredColorSpace`. Then, I convert this bitmap to a texture using `GLUtils.texImage2D` like this:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, // target
    0,             // level
    Source,        // bitmap
    0);            // border
```

My question is, why are the colors drawn correctly even though I didn't set up anything particular in OpenGL for handling different color spaces? Is OpenGL doing some automatic conversion or compatibility handling in the background? Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure they're drawn correctly? How do you know? I see the test image as a red square, but that's probably something in my browser or operating system not displaying an image it doesn't understand. Red is still red, green is still green and blue is still blue in P3, Adobe RGB, or any other RGB colour space, just as in sRGB. It's expected that green pixels are still green pixels if you interpret in the wrong colour space - just the wrong shade of green.

Comment: @user253751 it's drawing correctly because me i can see the logo on the red square :) when i convert the image to sRGB then i can not see anymore the logo. Why without any settings in my openGL surface, my app can show the P3 color space gamut ?

Comment: why can you see the logo in the red square but not in sRGB? do you know the pixel values? (i have no idea how to work with a P3 image)

Comment: @user253751 : all explanation here why their is a logo inside the image : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/wide-color-photos-are-coming-to-android.html

Comment: I suppose the logo in the test image is redder than the maximum sRGB red, so when converted, it turns out the same as the red background. Something like 255/255 P3 red for the logo and 200/255 P3 red for the background (I can't see it and can't be bothered to find the tool to tell me the actual values). if you have P3 display then it's displayed as 255/255 P3 red and 200/255 P3 red. If you have an sRGB display both are converted to 255/255 sRGB red with no difference. If you display 200/255 sRGB red and 255/255 sRGB red it's the wrong shade of red but still visible.